# Regression analysis with single outcome variable and binary independent variables

Tags: multiple-regression, meta-analysis, binary-data, odds-ratio

This is a meta-analysis. I'm looking at factors associated with vaccine acceptance in many countries. Looking at previous studies in different countries, I recorded factors that are associated with vaccine acceptance in general in each country. So, I have an excel sheet with the factors listed as columns and the countries (grouped according to their world bank income level) as rows. I want to do a regression analysis and get Odds ratio, 95%CI and p value to show how (to what extent): each of these factors are associated with vaccine acceptance in general, globally.
So, the outcome is a single outcome (vaccine acceptance). The independent variables (factors associated with vaccine acceptance) are binary (1,0); present or absent for each country in the World Bank income levels.

Link to the excel file
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k5J1mvKoon2rOOI_cl4j-0H6L2VmP25o/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106263038334256593043&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! Can you clarify what you are asking? There shouldn't be any problem with running some type of regression to investigate the research question you specify, but in your Excel sheet, your intended outcome variable (vaccine rate?) only has one value (same for all cases/rows), so I assume you have data somewhere that encodes varying vaccine acceptance across your cases?

Comment: Hi, yes I do have values for different countries. The factors in the excel sheet (younger, male......) are factors that were identified already (using regression analysis as factors associated with high vaccine acceptance) in different studies in the respective countries. Now I'm doing a synthesis (meta-analysis) to show how these factors are associated with vaccine acceptance globally. Even though I have individual vaccine acceptance value for each country, I want to analyze them globally as simply "vaccine acceptance". Hence, how do I modify these factors (binary) to do a regression analyz?

Comment: Just to add that I'm a beginner in R and I hope I have formulated my question correctly to permit a statistical analysis. I will like to get the Odds Ratio, 95%Cl, p value for each of the factors in relation to how well they are associated with vaccine acceptance

Comment: Ah, OK! Sorry, I thought you wanted to do a regression with countries as cases. You did say synthesis so I should have realized. I have no experience of a meta-analysis done this way, I have learned that for a meta-analysis you need to choose a "singular" effect of interest (e.g. the effect of income level on vaccine acceptance) and then you find the relevant studies focusing on this effect and compute the meta-analytical effect size (and then you can explore other predictors as possible moderators of this effect). I hope someone with more experience pitches in!

Comment: It is hard to see how you can estimate an odds ratio with just vaccine acceptance as an outcome as odds ratios compare two conditions.

Comment: I'm an statistics/R beginner. I think I have an issue with terminology. I know what I want but do not know how it is called. I want a measures of effect for each of these factors on vaccine acceptance. NOTE: These factors have been published as having an effect on vaccine acceptance. NOW: I want to do a synthesis to see to what extend (measures of effect) each of these factors affect vaccine acceptance.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate effect size using frequencies/proportions?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How to do that depends on how you are going to use frequencies or proportions (I can't seem to wrap my head around what is it that you want to do exactly).